# aws s3 sync failing on strange characters in filename

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm having an issue syncing files from an S3 bucket to my local disk. The AWS CLI  sync commands falls over on these two files with strange (unicode?) characters.

Is there a way to skip/ignore these and continue the sync?

This is what I'm trying to run, and the command just stops and returns without any error.

```
$ aws --profile MYPROFILE s3 sync s3://my-bucket-name my-local-directory/
download: s3://my-bucket-name/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2014/04/Hills_Ã‚_HSC_221.pdf to my-local-directory/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2014/04/Hills_Ã‚_221.pdf
download: s3://my-bucket-name/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2014/04/Hills_Ã‚_HSC_22.pdf to my-local-directory/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2014/04/Hills_Ã‚_22.pdf
download: s3://my-bucket-name/wp-content/uploads/random-other-file.pdf to my-local-directory/wp-content/uploads/random-other-file.pdf
$
```

First time I ran it there were 100s of files before it fell over, subsequent runs just goes straight to these files and dies. Worth noting, is that the 2 'bad' files and that third normal one are all successfully downloaded but the sync is far from finished.

For the record, relevant or not, I'm on an OSX Extended file system locally.

Comment: Have you tried s3cmd? It might have more robust handling of invalid filenames.